# Which subject/object does "their" refer to in this sentence?

Tags: pronouns

Consider "their" in the following sentence:

> **Existential psychologists** differed from **others** often classified as humanistic in **their** comparatively neutral view of human nature and in **their** relatively positive assessment of anxiety.

Is **their** referring to **existential psychologists** or **others**?
Is there any general rule for such cases?

I didn't know what to search for, so an external link or even a name to search for would also be good.

Comment: I think it's for *psychologists.* I tried this way - *white people (who?) differed from black people often classified as 'people with fair skin' in their appearance. :)

Answer (score 6):

Grammatically, it's ambiguous:

> 1. Existential psychologists differed from [**others** often classified as humanistic in **their** comparatively neutral view of human nature and in **their** relatively positive assessment of anxiety].
> 2. **Existential psychologists** differed from [others often classified as humanistic] in **their** comparatively neutral view of human nature and in **their** relatively positive assessment of anxiety.

So in theory, either is possible.

Practically speaking, reading 1 seems unlikely.  The sentence as a whole seems like it's intended to describe "existential psychologists", so reading 2 is more natural.  But to be sure, we need [additional context or information you didn't include](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psychology).  In context, only reading 2 makes sense; these psychologists embraced existential angst à la Kierkegaard or Sartre.

As for a general rule?  **Go for what makes sense in context.**  Isolating complex sentences almost always makes them harder to interpret.

Comment: +1 Here's a paraphrase: **Existential psychologists, unlike the other humanistic psychologists, had a comparatively neutral view of human nature and a relatively positive assessment of anxiety.** The "Humanistic Existential Psychologists" are being compared to other humanistic psychologists.  The original source has more context (as you say) that confirms this interpretation. :)

Answer (score 5):

Yes, the sentence is ambiguous, at least at the first reading.

- If the two *in* phrases modify/complement *differ*, the two *their*s refer to *existential psychologists*.
- If the phrases modify/complement *classified*, the *their*s refer to *others*.

Alas, there's no general rule for readers to disambiguate bad writing; it has to happen on the writer's side.

I would guess that in this case the *their*s refer to *existential pyschologists*, because with *classify*, ***in*** ordinarily heads phrases describing categories ("classified **in** the top quartile") rather than criteria ("classified **by** their view of human nature"). But I have no confidence in  this author's sensitivity to such matters.

Comment: Yes! And in addition, that author got into trouble as soon as they said "differed from" which led to the awkward form, "A differed from B in their Attribute1 and in their Attribute2."